# Flutter Unable to delete last item in AnimateList

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a todo list with AnimatedList. I am able to add new todos but am unable to delete them without having any error. My problem here is that whenever I delete the last todo, this error shows up: Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0.

[image]

This is the code for my delete todo

```
// delete goal
  void deleteGoal(int index) {
    if (db.dailyList.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(index, (context, animation) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: Tile(
          title: db.dailyList[index][0],
          goalAchieved: db.dailyList[index][1],
          onChanged: (value) =>
              {checkBoxChanged(value, index), achievedGoal(index)},
          deleteFunction: (context) => deleteGoal(index),
        ),
      );
    });
    setState(() {
      db.dailyList.removeAt(index);
      for (int i = index; i < db.dailyList.length; i++) {
        db.dailyList[i][2] = i;
      }
    });
    db.updateDatabase();
  }
```

Comment: Did you tried to add ` if (db.dailyList.length==0)` condition instead of `isEmpty` condition?

Comment: @CavinMacwan yup, same thing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the `list` has `n` items. you are deleting last item, and the `index` is `n-1` (because list indexing starts from zero). When you delete last item, `index` is still remaining `n-1`. In the last `for` loop, you are trying to iterate the list from `n-1`, but the currect value should be `n-2` (because one item is deleted and the list size decreased).

Conclusion: `db.dailyList.removeAt(index)` >> `for (int i = index; ...` >> `db.dailyList[i]` makes error

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Any suggestions on how i should tackle this then? I would say reindex is important as it allows me to delete things in any order i want and keep the animation as well

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to keep the index as third part of your list items while you can access to the index of each item by a simple for loop. And when you use the removeAt(index) function, the item is deleted, so there is no reason for reindexing. 
Anyway, for keep animating, there is some examples and tutorials, like these links (i hope they help):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54376329/4650581
https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-animatedlist-tutorial-and-examples/
https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-animate-items-in-list-using-animatedlist-in-flutter-9b1a64e9aa16